# Sort a list of navigation links alphabetically

Tags: c#, sorting

I have a list of navigation links that I want to sort alphabetically, but I'm having trouble doing so.

```
private void SetMarketDrop(Item CurrentItem)
{
    Item MarketParent = CurrentItem.Axes.SelectSingleItem(@"child::*[@@templatename='gojoMarketGrouping']");
    if (MarketParent == null)
        MarketDropArea.Visible = false;
    else
    {
        MarketHeader.Text = MarketParent.Fields["Home Page  Drop Down"].Value;
        Item[] MarketSet = MarketParent.Axes.SelectItems("descendant-or-self::*[@@templatename='gojoMarketLanding' and @Hidden Page != '1' and @Hide from DropDown != '1']");
        if (MarketSet == null)
            MarketDropArea.Visible = false;
        else
        {
            foreach (Item MarketItem in MarketSet)
                MarketLinks.Text += string.Format("<a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>", ScHelper.GetRegionPath(MarketItem), MarketItem.Fields["Menu Title"].Value);
        }
    }
}
```

This bit of code displays all the necessary navigation items, but they aren't in the correct order. I don't know if it would be easier to sort the "Menu Title" fields first then add hyperlinks, or if there is a way to do it in one step. I tried converting what is in the MarketLinks text field to a CharArray and sorting that alphabetically, but it did not work as expected.

Comment: Share more code.  I only see you adding one item to MarketLinks.  Where do you think the sorting is done that is failing?

Comment: Is MarketSet sorted?

Comment: Just forget what you are doing right now, wait a few minutes, and read your question as a refreshed brain. Do you understand anything

Comment: I added the foreach that is populating the MarketLinks. I was trying to sort the list of links after building it (basically, after the foreach, but that did not work.

Comment: What is MarketSet?  Is it a sortable type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you tried something like this?

```
foreach (Item MarketItem in MarketSet.OrderBy(x => x.Fields["Menu Title"].Value))
  MarketLinks.Text += string.Format("<a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>", ScHelper.GetRegionPath(MarketItem), MarketItem.Fields["Menu Title"].Value);
```

May the Doctor be with you.

Comment: That is what I wanted! I tried using .OrderBy, but never thought to use it like that. It seems to have corrected the issue, so thanks!